# How to pass response body via res.send or res.jsonn in express from response inside callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'a newbie in expressjs, want to ask a question, how to pass body *chunk / data* from callback response into res.send() or res.json(). here my code :

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {
const httpOptions = {
        hostname: '...com.sg',
        port: 443,
        path: '...',
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            Authorization: Signatures ,
            ApiKey: '...',
            ApiSecret: '...',
            FINS: fins      
        }  
    }
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    console.log('headers:', httpOptions.headers);
    const callback = function(response) {

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log(`statusCode: ${response.statusCode}`)
            console.log('Body: ' + chunk);     
        });

        response.on('end', function () {

        });
      }

     var req = https.request(httpOptions, callback).end();


res.send(req.body);
// res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))

next()

});
```

When i check in console it seems Ok, and give me response like what i want something like :

```
Body: {"status":"Ok","workPassEntries":[{"fin":"F.......A","status":"ObjectNotFound","workPass":null}]}
```

But the other hand give me empty body in browser and in postman, apologize for confusing question because i'm newbie, thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, You need to invoke `res.send()` inside the callback block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it solved!, with directly request using this code :

```
let data = '';

  let apiRequest = https.request( options, function(res) {
    console.log("Connected");

    res.on("data", chunk => {     
      data += chunk;
      console.log('Body: ' + chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
      console.log("Data Verified");
      console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
      response.end(data);

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `res.send()` inside the callback function:

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {
const httpOptions = {
        hostname: '...com.sg',
        port: 443,
        path: '...',
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            Authorization: Signatures ,
            ApiKey: '...',
            ApiSecret: '...',
            FINS: fins      
        }  
    }
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    console.log('headers:', httpOptions.headers);
    const callback = function(response) {

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log(`statusCode: ${response.statusCode}`)
            console.log('Body: ' + chunk);
            //Here you can send the stream of data to client side
            res.send(chunk);    
        });

        response.on('end', function () {

        });
      }

     var req = https.request(httpOptions, callback).end();

next()

});
```

Comment: Halo there, thanks for answer, i've testing to invoke res.send(chunk) as your suggestion, ,but still no luck.

Comment: Here in NodeJS documents does the same, just write the response to a standard out put, res is a standard output. https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback